# Problema navegador Opera y Egde con petición JSON

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, php7, navegador-web

He hecho una web con php, javascript y alguna peticion JSON. Todo correcto y se ve bien en todos los navegadores salvo un detalle. Hay un pequeño buscador que al ir escribiendo va haciendo busquedas. En todos los navegadores va bien menos opera y Egde de Microsoft que me sale una pantallita y me dice:

Localhost devuelve null

Solo lo hacen estos navegadores. ¿Que puedo hacer? Aviso en la web no usar estos navegadores o hay algun método para solucionarlo.

Bueno os pongo código, pero tengo unas 15 consultas iguales y solo es esa la que me produce el error. Cada vez que pulsas una tecla hace la peticion a la bbdd y resuelve. Vamos como hace GOOGLE. Como digo todo funciona perfecto menos en esos navegadores.

```
///No uso AJAX para hacer la peticion en este caso

petBuscador = ConBuscador.conection();
petBuscador.onreadystatechange = procesaRespuesta;
petBuscador.open('POST', "../Controlador/Elementos_AJAX/busquedas.php?", true);
petBuscador.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
petBuscador.send(parametros);


Tal vez deberia probar con AJAX
```

---

Hola a todos ayer me fui a trabajar y no os pude poner nada. Bueno comento que esta petición esta hecha de la misma manera que otras 20 que tengo en la web. Todas funcionan perfectamente en todos los navegadores. La unica diferencia es que esta se ejecuta cada vez que pulsas una tecla. Pero en IE,FIREFOX,CROME funciona. Os voy a poner primero una captura de lo que me dice la consola de Edge.

[image: este es el error]

Pero si ejecuto el script PHP desde Netbeans si funciona:

[image: Script PHP funciona]

Bueno ahora os pongo el código.

Primero creo un metodo que crea la petición y la devuelve:

```
function Conexion() {


this.READY_STATE_UNINITIALIZED = 0;
this.READY_STATE_LOADING = 1;
this.READY_STATE_LOADED = 2;
this.READY_STATE_INTERACTIVE = 3;
this.READY_STATE_COMPLETE = 4;

this.conection = function devuelvoConexionAJAX() {
 
        if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
            peticion = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
        }else if (window.ActiveXObject){
                peticion= new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP'); 
            }
      
        return peticion;
             

};
```

Luego monto la petición:

```
case('ENCONTRADO'):
        petEncontrado = ConBuscador.conection();
        petEncontrado.onreadystatechange = procesaRespuesta;
        petEncontrado.open('POST', "../Controlador/Elementos_AJAX/busquedas.php?", true);
        petEncontrado.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        petEncontrado.send(parametros);


Y el código PHP devuelve un objeto con encode_json que si funciona. Voy a ver si creando una peticion $.ajax me funciona.
```

Comment: ok, entonces la solución seria que  arregles el buscador, para que funcione en edge y opera? o como dices avisa para que no usen esos navegadores... necesitarias detectar el navegador... como lo hacen aqui: https://www.solvetic.com/tutoriales/article/1634-detectar-el-navegador-con-javascript/

Comment: Edita la pregunta para agregar el código de la petición y lo que haces en PHP para identificar el error. Yo tengo un script similar y funciona sin problemas en los navegadores recientes: Firefox, Chromium y derivados (Chrome, Opera, Edge)

Comment: Lo que pasa en PHP no tiene nada que ver con el navegador, si estas en localhost, solo revisa si los headers se estan enviando correctamente, puede ser que haya navegadores mas flexibles en esto

Comment: Prueba con ajax para que el server te devuelva success/fail en la peticion

Comment: El código que publicaste no es suficiente para saber lo que estás haciendo y, de hecho, parece que sí usas AJAX, pero por medio de una clase u objeto `ConBuscador`. La parte importante que falta es ver cómo armas los parámetros en Javascript y cómo tratas de obtenerlos en PHP

Answer (score 0):

Bueno chicos pues cambie la petición a una AJAX y ya me funciona. No entiendo por que solo me ocurre con esta peticion. Igual es que consume mucho tiempo.Os pongo la imagen de la petición AJAX, la he ido toqueteando , la verdad que es de las primeras veces que las utilizo.
Si teneis cualquier consejo por favor darmelo.
[image: Petición AJAX básica]

Y muchas gracias chicos ....